# Image resolution not showing up in "Get info" dialog in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, finder

When I bought a Mac Mini with Mac OS X, I could show image dimensions in the *Get Info* dialog.

After that, I installed some mobile application development software and later I noticed, *Get Info* was not showing the image dimensions anymore. I need to check the dimensions of those images to include artwork in my project. Now, I reinstalled my Mac OS X and it's working fine – it is showing the dimensions:

[image]

Before that, 516x314 was missing. Why did that happen? How can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: It would really help if you told us what mobile application development software you installed.

Comment: I installed Xcode 4.2, Eclipse Juno and Source Tree for tracking git ang Git too.

Comment: Hm. That shouldn't have caused anything, actually, but knowing whether it's the combination of these apps or just a single one would help. Have you reinstalled all of them again? I guess it was just a hiccup from Spotlight. Maybe restarting and reindexing Spotlight would have helped.

Comment: Were the files [excluded from the Spotlight index](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26582/image-dimensions-infos-on-lion-finder-columns-view)?

Comment: @slhck I forgot to say that. I had another issue with spotlight. Now i just remembering from your comment. My Spotlight indexing wasn't yet finished for a long time too. Now I am thinking that problem arised because of that spotlight problem.

Comment: @LauriRanta I had an exact problem what they discussed in your link given. But I didn't add any of my folders to exclude from Spotlight.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem too .. but I noticed something, if I check an image's info I get the resolution , but if I close that and check again the resolution disappears :s , so I can only check it once >.<

Comment: Ya.. I got like that too.. When I do like that, suggested by @slhck in answer, its get rid of the problem sometimes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions (and other metadata) of a file are stored in the Spotlight index, which allows you to [effectively search for specific features](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/03/digging-deeper-mastering-spotlight-in-os-x/). If the image dimensions are not available, this is likely caused by the files not being indexed, or the index being broken.

To solve this, try the following:

- In any case, check *System Preferences » Spotlight » Privacy*. Is any folder containing these images listed there? If yes, remove it from the list.
- To [force-reindex Spotlight](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409), you can just add your entire hard drive to this *Privacy* list, and immediately remove it again.

Comment: Now I don't have issues as I said. If I got any issues like that, then I will do as you said. Thank You so much:-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (on Mac):

1. Open the picture in Preview App
2. Either:
3. - click: Cmd+i
4. Or:
5. - click: Tools menu
6. - click: Show Inspector
7. Inspector opens a General Info window. Pixes are shown in the Image Size row.